# Doctrine error Symfony 3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've got fos_user entity that is in relation OneToOne with reservedArea entity.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\ReservedArea", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reserved", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $reserved;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getReserved()
    {
        return $this->reserved;
    }

    public function setReserved($reserved)
    {
        $this->reserved = $reserved;
    }
}
```

In my reservedArea entity i've got only a OneToMany relation with File entity.

```
class ReservedArea
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File", mappedBy="reserved_area", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $file;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->file = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add file
     *
     * @param \ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File $file
     *
     * @return ReservedArea
     */
    public function addFile(\ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File $file)
    {
        $this->file[] = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove file
     *
     * @param \ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File $file
     */
    public function removeFile(\ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File $file)
    {
        $this->file->removeElement($file);
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

And in my File entity i've got just a simple string.

```
class File
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\ReservedArea", inversedBy="file")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reserved_area", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $reservedArea;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set reservedArea
     *
     * @param \ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\ReservedArea $reservedArea
     *
     * @return File
     */
    public function setReservedArea(\ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\ReservedArea $reservedArea = null)
    {
        $this->reservedArea = $reservedArea;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get reservedArea
     *
     * @return \ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\ReservedArea
     */
    public function getReservedArea()
    {
        return $this->reservedArea;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return File
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
```

Now if i try to access to user file doing something like that :

```
$files = $this->getUser()->getReserved()->getFile();
foreach($files as $file) {
    var_dump($file); //or $file->getFile();
}
```

I get an error :

> Notice: Undefined index: reserved_area

In my database I add an user with a reserved area and two file and if i direct make :

```
SELECT u.username, f.file FROM fos_user u INNER JOIN reserved_area r ON u.reserved=r.id INNER JOIN reserved_area_file f ON f.reserved_area=r.id;
```

I get in output the right result.
Where i'm going wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem and I post it beacause maybe will help someone.
The problem is here:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ReservedAreaBundle\Entity\File", mappedBy="reserved_area", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $file;
```

I can't use in mappedBy the name of the table in @JoinColumn(name="reserved_are") but I have to use the name of the attribute.
So :

```
mappedBy="reservedArea"
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I answered the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35969467/1
which was then edited by the author.

---

The annotation mapping of `$reservedArea` in `File` class is incorrect.
The `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` attributes must always contain name of the attribute from entity on the other side of the association.
So in your case `File::$reservedArea` should have `inversedBy="file"`.

See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional for more examples.